# How to properly ping JGroups

Tags: netcat, jgroups

I have a jgroup-based app and use netcat to check if the app is up and running (healthcheck in Marathon, managing applications start order):

```
nc -z -w 1 app 7801
```

Everything is fine apart the jgroup logs which have the following exceptions:

```
WARN  org.jgroups.protocols.TCP - JGRP000006: failed accepting connection from peer
app        | java.io.EOFException: null
app        |        at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
app        |        at org.jgroups.blocks.TCPConnectionMap$TCPConnection.readPeerAddress(TCPConnectionMap.java:511)
app        |        at org.jgroups.blocks.TCPConnectionMap$TCPConnection.<init>(TCPConnectionMap.java:381)
app        |        at org.jgroups.blocks.TCPConnectionMap$Acceptor.handleAccept(TCPConnectionMap.java:303)
app        |        at org.jgroups.blocks.TCPConnectionMap$Acceptor.run(TCPConnectionMap.java:287)
app        |        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is there a way to "ping" a jgroup application in a more appropriate way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If diagnostics are enabled (`enable_diagnostics` in the transport, e.g. `UDP` or `TCP`), you can use probe.sh or netcat to extract information from all or or individual cluster members.

By default, port `7500` on `224.0.75.75` is used, but these attributes can be set as well.

You could also write a simple `HEALTH` protocol which opens a socket (TCP or datagram) and responds to simple are-you-alive requests, e.g. by sending back a single byte.